# How to construct hyperbolically equidistant points on a line?

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, geometric-construction

In Stillwells' "Sources of Hyperbolic Geometry " [page 66 figure 3.3](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ZQjBXxxQsucC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA66) shows an ((incomplete?) construction of  hyperbolically equidistant points on a line.

[image: Figure in question, taken from Klein 1928 via gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de]

I tried to reconstruct the figure but did not manage it can anybody tell me how this figure is constructed?

Or another way to construct hyperbolically equidistant points on a line.

Comment: The picture doesn't work. If its a vertical line, you just want the ratios of the heights to be equal.

Comment: @BrianRushton: This is the Klein model of hyperbolic geometry, so verticality of lines is completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm looking at the original source: Felix Klein „[Vorlesungen über nicht-euklidische Geometrie](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN375534636&IDDOC=286471)“, page 172. The general idea is that the cross ratio $\operatorname{CR}(P_1,P_2;A,B)$ must be equal to the cross ratio $\operatorname{CR}(P_2,P_3;A,B)$ since length can be computed from that cross ratio. Now following Kleins description, the line $BA'$ is chosen arbitrarily through $B$, and the point $S$ is arbitrary as well. Then $A',P_1',P_2'$ follow by projection with center $S$ from line $AB$ to line $A'B$. Furthermore, $P_2P_1'$ intersects $AS$ in a point $M$, which can be used as the center of a second projection back onto $AB$. Since these projections preserve cross ratios, we have

$$
\operatorname{CR}(P_1,P_2;A,B)
\overset S=
\operatorname{CR}(P_1',P_2';A',B)
\overset M=
\operatorname{CR}(P_2,P_3;A,B)
$$

These steps can be repeated to form an arbitrary number of equidistant points. As the dashed lines indicate, you can use the same points $S$ and $M$ for all of them, only the intersection points on the line $A'B$ are different for every new point you transform. In essence, projection onto $A'B$ via $S$ then down to $AB$ via $M$ is a unit step of your sequence.